# Restrict all access to a s3 bucket and allow 1 IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

As a plan to deprecate s3 objects, I am revoking all access apart from mine. I tried 2 ways but I see I am not able to see the bucket policy.

Error message from console:

```
You don’t have permission to get bucket policy
You or your AWS administrator must update your IAM permissions to allow s3:GetBucketPolicy. After you obtain the necessary permission, refresh the page. Learn more about Identity and access management in Amazon S3
```

First:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::ck",
        "arn:aws:s3:::k/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:userId": [
            "AIDA"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Second:

```
{
            "Id": "bucketPolicy",
            "Statement": [
                    {
                            "Action": "s3:*",
                            "Effect": "Deny",
                            "NotPrincipal": {
                                    "AWS": [
                                            "arn:aws:iam::0220:user/an"
                                    ]
                            },
                            "Resource": [
                                    "arn:aws:s3:::tes",
                                    "arn:aws:s3:::tes/*"
                            ]
                    }
            ],
            "Version": "2012-10-17"
    }
```

Comment: There was no bucket policy. I do for other buckets.

Comment: You seem to be saying that you tried these two bucket policies and both times your IAM user (named ‘an’) invoked GetBucketPolicy, it failed with AccessDenied. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes..I was able to add bucket policy in two different bucket and two different way as mentioned and after that when I go to permission tab I see the error message.

Comment: You could have locked yourself out of bucket policy. You can check [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-accidentally-denied-access/) if this is the case.